# How to set a column to PRIMARY KEY while merging two tables using inner join?(there is no primary key in the two joining tables)

Tags: mysql

How to set a column to `PRIMARY KEY` while merging two tables using **inner join**?(*there is no primary key in the two joining tables*) please help.

```
create table merge_aws AS
select aws.id,aws.date,aws.time,aws.pmer,aws.dd,aws.ff,aws.t,masterfile.station,masterfile.latitude,masterfile.longitude
from aws
inner join masterfile
on aws.id=masterfile.call_sign;
```

Comment: @Roey that was a heck of an edit there :p

Comment: @Roey Golzarpoor ANSWERS to the question are also welcomed! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use alter table after creation like this sample:

```
CREATE TABLE merge_aws AS select 
    aws.id,
    aws.date,
    aws.time,
    aws.pmer,
    aws.dd,
    aws.ff,
    aws.t,
    masterfile.station,
    masterfile.latitude,
    masterfile.longitude
from
    aws
        inner join
    masterfile ON aws.id = masterfile.call_sign;

ALTER TABLE merge_aws ADD COLUMN prim INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , ADD PRIMARY KEY (prim) ;
```

Thanks

Comment: ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'id'

Comment: ALTER TABLE merge_aws ADD COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , ADD PRIMARY KEY (id) ;

Comment: i want to set " id " as PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: i dont want to add another column but, set existing " id " as PRIMARY KEY.